# how to convert this HTML file into a PDF using python

Tags: python, html, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I am having a process where my python code needs to generate a PDF.

I have an HTML file as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./proforma_supply_bill.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla:wght@400;600;700&family=Rajdhani:wght@700&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Proforma bill of supply</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: "Karla", sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }

        th,
        td {
            padding: 0 !important;
            text-align: left;
            position: relative;
        }

        .mb-3 {
            margin-bottom: 3px;
        }

        .mb-5 {
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .pr-10{
            padding-right: 10px !important;
        }

        .text-right {
            text-align: right;
        }

        .border-b_color {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #93d150;
        }

        .border-t {
            border-top: 1px solid #dedede;
        }

        .border-b {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
        }

        .card {
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 0 20px;
        }

        .card__header,
        .card__total_amount,
        .card__amount_section {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
            padding: 17px 0;
        }

        .card__header_img {
            width: 175px;
        }

        .card__header_title {
            font-family: "Rajdhani", sans-serif;
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #2b9eaa;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        .card__info_flex {
            display: flex;
            padding: 10px 0;
        }

        .card__info {
            flex: 50%;
        }

        .card__info_row:not(:last-child) {
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .card__info_title,
        .card__table_data_row__content {
            color: #141414;
            font-size: 15px;
        }

        .card__info_text {
            color: #141414;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .card__table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        .card__table_header_row {
            background-color: #2b9eaa;
        }

        .card__table_data_row {
            border-top: 1px solid #dedede;
        }

        .card__table_header_row__content {
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 6px 0;
        }

        .card__table_data_row__content {
            padding: 5px 0;
        }

        .card__table_data_row__subcontent {
            font-size: 13px;
            color: #141414;
            width: max-content;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }

        .dashed_b-t {
            border-top: 1px dashed #dedede;
        }

        .card__total_amount {
            background-color: #F2F2F2;
            padding: 4px 10px 5px;
            border-top: 1px solid #dedede;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
        }

        .card__amount_section {
            padding: 6px 10px 5px;
            align-items: flex-start;
        }

        .card__total_amount__title,
        .card__total_amount__title_lg {
            font-size: 18px;
            color: #141414;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .card__declaration {
            padding: 6px 10px 5px;
            background-color: #D4ECEE;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #2b2b2b;
        }

        .card__signature {
            margin-top: 30px;
            padding: 0 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card__header border-b_color">
            <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/exportify/image/upload/v1573547246/ExportifyLogo/exportify_logo_166x31_OG_yhqmrg.svg"
                alt="Exportify Logo" class="card__header_img">
            <div class="card__header_title">PROFORMA Bill of Supply</div>
        </div>

        <div class="card__info_flex border-b_color">
            <div class="card__info">
                <div class="card__info_row">
                    <span class="card__info_title">Proforma Invoice No.: </span>
                    <span class="card__info_text">{{PROFORMA_INV_NO}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="card__info_row">
                    <span class="card__info_title">Reference No. & Date.: </span>
                    <span class="card__info_text">{{REF_NO}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="card__info_row">
                    <span class="card__info_title">Buyer's Order No.: </span>
                    <span class="card__info_text">{{BUYER_ORDER_NO}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="card__info_row">
                    <span class="card__info_title">Vessel/Flight No.: </span>
                    <span class="card__info_text">{{VESSEL_NAME}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="card__info_row">
                    <span class="card__info_title">City/Port of Loading: </span>
                    <span class="card__info_text">{{POL}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="card__info_row">
                    <span class="card__info_title">Terms of Delivery: </span>
                    <span class="card__info_text">{{DELIVERY_TERMS}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card__info">
                <div class="card__info_row">
                    <span class="card__info_title">Dated: </span>
                    <span class="card__info_text">{{INV_DATE}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="card__info_row">
                    <span class="card__info_title">SAIL Date: </span>
                    <span class="card__info_text">{{SAIL_DATE}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="card__info_row">
                    <span class="card__info_title">Place of Receipt by Shipper: </span>
                    <span class="card__info_text">{{PLACE_OF_RECEIPT}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="card__info_row">
                    <span class="card__info_title">City/Port of Discharge: </span>
                    <span class="card__info_text">{{POD}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card__info_flex" style="padding-bottom: 0;">
            <div class="card__info"></div>
            <div class="card__info mb-3">
                <span class="card__info_title">Buyer (Bill to)</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card__info_flex" style="padding-top: 0;">
            <div class="card__info">
                <div class="card__info_text mb-3">XPORTIFY TECHNOLOGIES PRIVATE LIMITED</div>
                <div class="card__info_title mb-5" style="line-height: 20px; width: 85%;">
                    3rd Floor, 313-314, A/3, BGTA Ganga Premises, Wadala Truck Terminal, Near Wadala RTO, Wadala East,
                    Mumbai
                </div>
                <div class="card__info_row">
                    <span class="card__info_title">GSTIN/UIN: </span>
                    <span class="card__info_text">27AAACX2283M1ZX</span>
                </div>
                <div class="card__info_row">
                    <span class="card__info_title">PAN No: </span>
                    <span class="card__info_text">AAACX2283M</span>
                </div>
                <div class="card__info_title mb-5">State Name: Maharashtra, Code: 27</div>
                <div class="card__info_row">
                    <span class="card__info_title">CIN: </span>
                    <span class="card__info_text">U74999MH2017PTC295494</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card__info">
                <div class="card__info_text mb-3">{{BUYER_COMPANY_NAME}}</div>
                <div class="card__info_title mb-5" style="line-height: 20px;">
                    {{BUYER_ADDRESS}}
                </div>
                <div class="card__info_row">
                    <span class="card__info_title">GSTIN/UIN: </span>
                    <span class="card__info_text">{{BUYER_GST}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="card__info_title mb-5">State Name: {{BUYER_STATE}}</div>
                <div class="card__info_row">
                    <span class="card__info_title">Place of Supply: </span>
                    <span class="card__info_text">{{BUYER_PLACE_OF_SUPPLY}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <table class="card__table mb-5">
            <thead>
                <tr class="card__table_header_row">
                    <th>
                        <div class="card__table_header_row__content" style="padding-left: 10px;">Sr. No.</div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <div class="card__table_header_row__content">Description of Services</div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <div class="card__table_header_row__content">HSN/SAC</div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <div class="card__table_header_row__content">Quantity</div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <div class="card__table_header_row__content">Rate</div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <div class="card__table_header_row__content">Per</div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <div class="card__table_header_row__content text-right" style="padding-right: 10px;">
                            Amount
                        </div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="card__table_data_row">
                    <td>
                        <div class="card__table_data_row__content" style="padding-left: 10px;">1</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="card__table_data_row__content">Freight Charges</div>
                        <div class="card__table_data_row__subcontent">$ 1938/20x1x@74.97</div>
                        
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="card__table_data_row__content">996521</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="card__table_data_row__content">1</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="card__table_data_row__content">7,900.00</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="card__table_data_row__content">Container</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="card__table_data_row__content text-right pr-10" style="right: 0;">USD
                            7,900.00
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="card__total_amount mb-5">
            <div class="card__total_amount__title">Total</div>
            <div class="card__total_amount__title_lg">USD 7,900.00</div>
        </div>

        <div class="card__amount_section border-b mb-3">
            <div class="card__amount_section_flex">
                <div class="card__info_title mb-3">Amount Chargeable (in words)</div>
                <div class="card__info_text">USD Seven Thousand Nine Hundred Only</div>
            </div>
            <div class="card__amount_section_flex">
                <div class="card__info_title">E & O.E</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card__amount_section border-t">
            <div class="card__amount_section_flex">
                <div class="card__info_title">HSN/SAC</div>
            </div>
            <div class="card__amount_section_flex">
                <div class="card__info_title">Taxable Value</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card__amount_section border-t mb-3">
            <div class="card__amount_section_flex">
                <div class="card__info_title">996521</div>
            </div>
            <div class="card__amount_section_flex">
                <div class="card__info_title">INR 1,45,291.86</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card__total_amount mb-5">
            <div class="card__total_amount__title" style="font-size: 15px;">Total</div>
            <div class="card__total_amount__title_lg" style="font-size: 15px;">INR 1,45,291.86</div>
        </div>

        <div class="card__info_row" style="padding: 10px;">
            <span class="card__info_title">Tax Amount (in words): </span>
            <span class="card__info_text">NIL</span>
        </div>

        <div class="card__declaration">
            Declaration
        </div>

        <div class="card__info_title" style="padding: 10px;">
            We declare that this invoice shows the actual price of the goods described and that all particulars are true
            and correct.
        </div>

        <div class="card__info_text" style="padding: 0 10px;">
            for XPORTIFY TECHNOLOGIES PRIVATE LIMITED
        </div>

        <div class="card__signature">
            <div class="card__info_title">Authorised Signatory</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to convert this HTML file into a PDF using Python.
I have one option of using **wkhtmltopdf** package but I have to run it using the command line everytime.
Which is the most optimal way of doing this without hampering the flow of my code?

Comment: You can check [pdfme](https://github.com/aFelipeSP/pdfme) library. It's the most powerful library in python to create PDF documents.

Answer (score 3):

1. Install pdfkit package

   ```
    pip install pdfkit
   ```
2. Install wkhtmltopdf https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html
3. PDF to HTML in the current folder

   ```
   import pdfkit
   import glob
   ```

   3.1 Set wkhtmltopdf executable file path

   ```
   config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe')
   ```

   3.2 Convert all html files in the current folder

   ```
   for file in glob.glob('./*.html'):
       pdfkit.from_file(file, file[:-4]+'.pdf', configuration=config)
   ```